# Is there something like a sudoers list in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, sudo, uac, sudoers

In UNIX-like systems, normal users can obtain higher priviledges using the `sudo` command (or they can temporarily switch the user using `su`). However, with a properly configured `sudoers` and [PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/) file, you can prevent normal users from gaining higher priviledges completely, such that even if they were in possession of administrative credentials, they would have to login as that user.

In Windows UAC, whenever some application requires higher priviledged access, the currently logged in user is asked to type in the credentials of an priviledged account.

I was wondering if Windows provides a similar mechanism to `sudo`, to prevent normal users of getting higher access completely.

Comment: But even when `sudo` is blocked, you can still use `su` if you know the necessary credentials. That’s not exactly “prevented completely”.

Comment: @DanielB: You can effectively prevent users not in the `wheel`group from using `su` by setting `auth required pam_wheel.so use_uid` in PAM (specifically in `/etc/pam.d/su` - at least in Fedora Linux).

Comment: So I’ll just use another PAM service. ;) // Is [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-behavior-of-the-elevation-prompt-for-standard-users) perhaps what you’re looking for?

Comment: "So I’ll just use another PAM chain." - What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows will by default (in most cases) prompt for Admin credentials when an action requires elevation. This behavior is controlled by the [“User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for standard users”](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-behavior-of-the-elevation-prompt-for-standard-users) group policy. If set to “Automatically deny elevation requests”, the prompt will not show up.

This will, however, not prevent the user from using `runas` or similar tools to run a program with known Admin credentials. These methods are not related to UAC. The Explorer context menu entry can be disabled using the `HideRunAsVerb` DWORD at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\Explorer`

To fully harden a system, you need to use AppLocker to prevent execution of *all* unknown/undesired software.